# Python: find a string between the first occurrence of two substrings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a text like this:

```
text='gn="right" headers="gr-Y10 gr-eps i36">121.11<\\/td><\\/tr><tr class="hr"><td colspan="12"><\\/td><\\/tr><tr>'
```

I would like to get the value `121.11` using regex out of it.
So I did this:

```
import re
b=re.search('gr-Y10 gr-eps i36">(.*)<\\\\/td', text)
b.group(1)
```

and I got this as output:

```
'121.11<\\/td><\\/tr><tr class="hr"><td colspan="12">'
```

How can I get what I am really looking for, which is `121.11` instead of the line above?

Comment: From the last question you've asked I suspect that the input is HTML, correct? In this case, you need an HTML parser, better don't parse it with regexes.

Comment: :) yes it is HTML. Do you mean I use BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Yes, let me provide you with a solution here.

Comment: @alecxe thanks, looking forward to see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gr-Y10 gr-eps i36">(.*?)<\\\\/td

                      ^^
```

make your `*` non greedy by appending `?`.By making it non greedy it will stop at the first instance of `<\\\\/td` else it will capture upto last `<\\\\/td`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/2#python

Comment: thanks that worked. Also is then anythin I can use instead of \\\\ to match \\?

Comment: @TJ1 `gr-Y10 gr-eps i36">(.*?)<\\+/td` or use `r` mode

Comment: @TJ1 `print re.findall(r'gr-Y10 gr-eps i36">(.*?)<\\+/td',x)` here x is your test_strin

Answer (score 5):

Knowing the [source of the input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978362/scraping-a-website-with-clickable-content-in-python) and taking into account it is HTML, here is a solution involving an *HTML Parser*, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(input_data)

for row in soup.select('div#tab-growth table tr'):
    for td in row.find_all('td', headers=re.compile(r'gr-eps')):
        print td.text
```

Basically, for every row in the "growth" table, we are finding the cells with `gr-eps` in headers ("EPS %" part of the table). It prints:

```
60.00
—
—
—
—
42.22
3.13
—
—
—
-498.46
...
```

[This is a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) also.

Comment: @TJ1 thanks for getting me closer to the regex silver badge through providing non-regex answers to regex topics :)

Comment: hahaha!!!!!!!!!seems like somebody has exploited a loophole :P

Comment: @vks exactly, completely unintentionally :)